# Grab a color from the page with Google Chrome inspector

Tags: google-chrome

Firefox has a very usefull tool available as default on the inspector menu, it allows to inspect and grab a color from the page and copy its color code.
[image: grab a color from the page]
My current project requires us to use Google Chrome as the standard browser, which makes sense since is the most popular browser at the moment and most users use it. However, the inspector doesn't seem as easy to use as the one in Firefox (shown in the image above) and I would much appreciate if anyone could help me find this feature in Google Chrome.

I would like to grab a color from the page in google chrome inspector. I did research about it without luck, maybe I'm not using the right keywords to find what I'm looking for...

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it won't be exactly what you are looking for but I use a Google Chrome extension named "ColorZilla" to extract any color code.

Here is the link if you want to take a closer look: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/colorzilla/bhlhnicpbhignbdhedgjhgdocnmhomnp?hl=de